# Can I limit my child's PS4 screen time?

Tags: ps4

Is there an app that can control my son's PS4 screen time? He has been gaming a lot lately and I can't really control him. Or maybe is there a parental setting that can allow this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes**

On PS4 go to Settings > Parental Controls/ Family Management. There will be options to set different time limits:

> Allocate Play Times: ‘Time Duration’, ‘Playable Hours’ and ‘End Time’ for every day or specific days of the week.

Source: [Play Time Settings](https://www.playstation.com/en-za/get-help/help-library/my-account/parental-controls/play-time-settings/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is. Go to https://www.playstation.com/en-za/get-help/help-library/my-account/parental-controls/family-management/ to see the details. Basically, the function is within the settings.